# NHD layers won't redraw in ArcGIS 10.1 at small scale?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, scale, extents, nhd

If I am already zoomed in to a smaller scale and then add the NHD Hydrography dataset (already clipped to just Texas), I can see all the NHDFlowlines, NHDAreas, and other layers that come in the dataset.  If I try to do anything then (identify a feature, zoom in or out, pan, etc.), these layers do not redraw (though my shapefile layers do without any problem).  The only way I can get the NHD layers to draw again to zoom out to the full extent of Texas at which time they will start redrawing.  If I attempt to zoom in (with the mouse, the magnifying glass icon, or the zoom in arrows icon), the layers will not draw.  The machine that is having this problem runs ArcGIS 10.1.  On a different machine that has ArcGIS 10.2.2, I do not have this problem (starting from the same .mxd file).

Comment: just a check: are you within the visible scale range in the layer properties?  I know that the .lyr files that ship with NHD downloads have a visible scale range preset...

Comment: Thanks, mr.adam.  Actually, we checked that, and in the 'General' tab of the layer properties, the 'Show layer at all scales' was selected.  Also, the same project opened in ArcMap 10.2.2 didn't have the problem; it only happened when opened in ArcMap 10.1.

Answer (score 2):

You said that that you clipped them from a larger dataset. Did you rebuild the spatial index on the output shapefiles? Inappropriate spatial indices will cause the type of behavior in ArcMap that you described, wherein you can only view the data at the smallest scale/full extent.

In ArcCatalog, right-click the property of each shapefile, go to the Index tab, and if there is a spatial index, update it. If not, create one.

You can also use the python window or a script to rebuild the spatial index.

Also "smaller scale" indicates zoomed out, full extent being the smallest practical scale. Think of the scale as a ratio and this will be evident. E.g., 1:10000 (1/10000) is smaller than 1:100 (1/100). So, you seem to mean that the layers will not display at larger scales.

Comment: Thank-you for replying, and yes, I mean they wouldn't display at larger scales (excuse my typo). I actually did not clip anything myself; our GIS lab provided all the layers for Texas on our server. They work fine on one machine, but not on another, so I feel it was something in the settings of that one particular instance of ArcMap on that particular machine causing the problem.  I use past tense, because we decided to upgrade everything to 10.3, and that solved the problem for us.  I would like to know what the issue was in case we ever encounter it again, but for now, it has been resolved.